# Is it OK to serve static files with Django for a small internal web app?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

To start with - my app is simple internal app for our team only, so it means ~10 users max, nothing from "high load" stuff, nothing facing external production Internet.

As I read from other posts and questions, the recommended way is to have users-facing nginx (on the host), some wsgi server (such as Gunicorn or uwsgi) in main Docker container and static server (such as nginx) for static serving.

But I feel that it becomes too much for my simple app, I don't really see a need in having two Docker containers. I would like to just use typical `manage.py runserver` and it would be so much easier and simpler. In almost all the posts I read it's mentioned that this is "insecure and inefficient" - but would you really care about this if your service is pure internal and for 5-10-20 users? 
Or is there any alternative to it which does not require you to set up separated static-serving server? I have read about Whitenoise, but if I understood correctly, it still requires you to do `manage.py collectstatic` first, which is very inefficient for local development.

Is using `manage.py` for also serving static is **so** inefficient? Would it be an acceptable approach to use it for small internal web tools?

Comment: `manage.py collectstatic first, which is very inefficient for local development` ???

Comment: When I develop locally, I use `manage.py runserver` and I don't want to run extra command like `collectstatic` each time when I change my scripts of css

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run `collectstatic` to use WhiteNoise. You just need to use this setting:

```py
WHITENOISE_USE_FINDERS = True
```

For more details see:
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#WHITENOISE_USE_FINDERS

This basically mimics the behaviour of runserver in production, which is fine for a small low-traffic internal app.